# How can I create a custom user in django without interfering with the default auth_user . I don't want my user table to inherit from AbstractBaseUser

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to have a user table to add data from django rest framework and use it for all login/ logout and auth related tasks. I don't want to extend the BaseUser or the AbstractBaseUser. Is this possible? How can I do this?

Comment: See [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/).

Comment: To integrate with most of the built-in auth related tasks your custom user model must implement/provide a lot of functionality, the Abstract models provide a core implementation of that functionality that you will have to write from scratch if you don't use them. Why do you not want to extend them?

Comment: Abstract Base User comes with a lot of additional tasks like creating the user manager and others. I hope to keep my user table which has nothing but phone number clutter free, which I think can be achieved with what has been mentioned by Yevgeniy kosmak

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.